# Grouped barplot with 95% confidence intervals in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, confidence-interval

I am trying to make a horizontal grouped barplot with 95% CIs in R.  I created a CSV file that contains all the data (see below).  My code so far is:

```
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Descriptor), position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=Upper_CI, ymin=Lower_CI), position= position_dodge(0.9), width=0.25)
  ylab("Prevalence (%)") +
  ylim(0,100)
```

When I enter this code on R, I get the result "NULL".  Can you please help me?  Let me know if you need more information.  Thanks!

[Data table (df_Graph)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L19na.png)

See above for description.

Comment: You don't seem to have passed your data frame to ggplot. Is there some code missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to have a `ggplot` call before your layers. If we take a reproducible version of your data frame:

```r
df <- data.frame(Descriptor = c("Not painful", "Not painful", "Not painful", 
                                "Painful", "Painful", "Painful"), 
                 Severity = c("Clear/mild", "Moderate", "Severe", "Clear/mild", 
                               "Moderate", "Severe"), 
                 Value = c(92.6, 77.9, 54.1, 7.4, 22.1, 45.9), 
                 Lower_CI = c(86.2, 68.7, 45.1, 3.9, 15.1, 37.2), 
                 Upper_CI = c(96.1, 84.9, 62.8, 13.8, 31.3, 54.9))
```

Then the code would be something like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(Severity, Value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Descriptor), position = position_dodge(0.8), 
           color = "black", alpha = 0.7, width = 0.6) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Lower_CI, ymax = Upper_CI, group = Descriptor), 
                position = position_dodge(0.8), width = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange2", "deepskyblue4")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Percentage")
```

[image]